# why is javascript function not running in webview

Tags: javascript, webview

I have a webapp running inside a webview.

what i am trying to achieve is that if the user looses internet connection and tries to navigate the site, he will be taken to a default offline page. on this page a pice of javascript is tunning every 5 seconds checking for a response from the server. if it gets a response then the page is redirected so they can carry on.

the functionality works in the browser. but It does not work in the webview, I have tried several methods, but cannot understand why this is not working.

the page loads from the app it is just basic html with the javascript function and also a button to try an onclick method for testing, of which it didnt work.  I am new to this arm of programming.

```
private WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        mywebView.loadUrl("example.com");
    } else {
        mywebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        mywebView.loadUrl("example.com");

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("offline.html");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String htmlString = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
       
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        mywebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        mywebView.evaluateJavascript("checkInternet() {" +
                "setInterval(function() {" +
            "fetch('http://localhost')" +
                    ".then(function(response) {" +
                "if (response.status === 200) {" +
                    "console.log('Internet is on!');" +
                    "window.location.href = 'http://localhost';" +
                "} else {" +
                    "console.log('Internet is off!');" +
                "}" +
           "}).catch(function() {" +
                "console.log('Internet is off!');" +
            "});" +
        "}, 5000);" +
    "}," ,null);

    }

    WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mywebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }

    mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        // Need to accept permissions to use the camera
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        }
    });

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                    final String failingUrl) {

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = assetManager.open("offline.html");

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
                String htmlString = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

                mywebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                inputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });

}



private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
        mywebView.goBack();
 ``   } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}
code here

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `function` keyword before `checkInternet()`?